# Issue switching between UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a Tab Bar Application as I can switch between `UIViewController` without losing any types of data. But now I want to change `UIViewController` using a `UIButton`. I have used the simple storyboard shortcut using Show.
But when I return in the main `UIViewController` I've lost all data and function.
How can I switch between `UIViewController` without recreating new `UIViewController` but coming back to the same.

Comment: Assuming you're popping from the new VC back to the original, nothing should be lost. Are you resetting parts of the view in `viewWillAppear:` or similar methods? As for the one you're pushing to from your initial view, you will need an instance variable to hold the new VC and only recreate if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: kindly explain the issue. it's not clear right now. (In case you're pushing a VC on navigation stack, data of previous one must not be lost. Or may be you're doing that in viewWillAppear or somewhere else in your code explicitly)

Comment: Are you resetting any data in `viewWillAppear` of the first view controller?

Comment: few solutions are available to you. choose the one that suit you the most :  1. if keeping the data is all you care about it, then manage it out of the view controllers (for example ,in a singleton. 2. if you really need to keep all thus view controllers alive at all time ,just put all of them inside a containers and into a root view controllers,and manage the switching part in it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a segue. It will instantiate a new instance of the destination view controller.

In the action of the UIButton say something like:

```
self.tabController.selectedIndex = 1 //or whatever the index of the view controller you want to switch to is
```